# How to add parent Context in jetty

Tags: jetty, contextpath

I wrote a contexthandler to map `http://hostname:9001/gm/test` as follow:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Server server = new Server(new QueuedThreadPool(8, 6));
    ServerConnector connector = new ServerConnector(server);
    connector.setPort(9001);
    server.setConnectors(new Connector[] { connector });

    HandlerCollection handler = new HandlerCollection();
    ContextHandler contextHandler = new ContextHandler("/gm");

    ContextHandlerCollection contexts = new ContextHandlerCollection();
    contexts.setHandlers(new Handler[] { new TestHandler("/test") });
    contextHandler.setHandler(contexts);

    handler.setHandlers(new Handler[] { contextHandler, new DefaultHandler() });
    server.setHandler(handler);
    server.start();
    server.dumpStdErr();
    server.join();
}
```

but it doesn't work. If I remove var contextHandler in up codes. request `http://localhost:9001/test`  it work.  invoked Testhandle.doHandle(). if I want add parent context path to all contextHandlers in ContextHandlerCollection, how to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A nested `ContextHandlerCollection` is not a context of its own, and are not additive to parent contexts.

A Handler only knows about itself and below, not what is above it.

Your code essentially says the following

```
Server
  + HandlerCollection
      + ContextHandler "/gm"
      |   + ContextHandlerCollection
      |       + TestHandler "/test"
      + DefaultHandler
```

If the incoming request is on `http://localhost:9001/gm/test` then the processing of that request will hit the `ContextHandler "/gm"` and allow that sub-tree to be processed (as it matches the incoming request).  Then it hits the `TestHandler "/test"` (Which I'm assuming does its own context path or target logic), and then doesn't match anymore as `/gm/test != /test` as the TestHandler knows nothing about the ContextHandler above it.

Your code could look like this ...

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Server server = new Server(new QueuedThreadPool(8, 6));
    ServerConnector connector = new ServerConnector(server);
    connector.setPort(9001);
    server.setConnectors(new Connector[] { connector });

    HandlerCollection handlers = new HandlerCollection();
    server.setHandler(handlers);

    ContextHandlerCollection contexts = new ContextHandlerCollection();

    String baseContext = "/gm";
    // map on "/gm/test"
    contexts.addHandlers(new TestHandler(baseContext + "/test"));
    // map on "/gm/foo"
    contexts.addHandlers(new FooHandler(baseContext + "/foo"));

    baseContext = "/odd";
    // map on "/odd/bar"
    contexts.addHandlers(new BarHandler(baseContext + "/bar"));

    handlers.setHandlers(new Handler[] { contexts, new DefaultHandler() });

    server.start();
    server.dumpStdErr();
    server.join();
}
```